In Blazor application, route with parameter on razor page does not load images and css on browser refresh
I have .Net 6 server side Blazor application. On razor page I have two routes for the page. @page "/empployee" as default and @page "/empployee/{Page:int}" for pagination.
@page "/empployee"
@page "/empployee/{Page:int}"

It's working all well (with switching between pages) untill I refresh browser when I am on /empployee/{Page:int} route. After refresh my css, images and some component do not load.
Refreshing browser on /empployee works fine.
I tried removing @page "/empployee" and making default page "/empployee/1". Then even on first load, it gives same problem on default page too. I tried changing iamges source path with "~/folderName". Still no change. Not sure how page cycle works and what's going wrong.
Adding code from MainLayout.razor
<div>
<div class="fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="container-fluid header-background">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="Images/xyz.jpg" style="width:80px; display: inline;" class="rounded-pill  d-none d-sm-block">                   
            </div>
            <h1 class="text-white mx-auto">Title</h1>
            <div id="userInfo">                   
                <CustomComponent />                       
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<NavMenu />

<main class="mainContent">
    <article class="content px-3">
        <div class="app-body">
            @Body
        </div>
    </article>
</main>

So, everything loads if route  "/empployee" or even "/empployee/2"; but if I refresh page on "/empployee/2", image does not load. NavMenu and header loads with no css.
I might be because of isolated css. Tried adding  in _host.cshtml. Still does not work.

This doesn't make sense with the information provided.  You need to show the page code.

Added page code
